# C# How do I compare and exchange two structs?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following program:

```
public class Program
{
    struct Foo
    {
        public int Bar;
        public int Zoo;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo a;
        Foo b;

        a.Bar = 5;
        a.Zoo = 2;
        b.Bar = 5;
        a.Zoo = 2;

        Foo c;
        c.Bar = 3;
        c.Zoo = 5;

        var result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref a, b, c);
    }
}
```

How can I make this compile?

Comment: By changing `Foo` to a class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, basically. The framework doesn't provide a way of performing atomic, lock-free operations on arbitrary structs.

Comment: @OP: If this limitation sounds odd, consider that the framework does provide atomic reference assignments, but not atomic struct assignments (See [C# Reference 5.5: Atomicity of variable references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278.aspx)).  This sounds reasonable once you recognize that references will normally be of size equal to 32bits or 64bits (depending on whether the app is 32bit or 64bit).  Remember, `CompareExchange` is exchanging references, not instances.